# bta-lib error : trying to use rsi indicator but gives ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value

Tags: python, pandas, finance, binance, indicator

Im trying to use bta-lib to calculate rsi indicator although it was fine with the sma function but through an error on rsi function
'''

```
df=pd.read_csv('prices.csv')
sma=btalib.sma(df,period=9)#works fine
rsi=btalib.rsi(df,period=14)#through an error
```

'''
error= ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value...
my df len is enough.
[image: prices.csv]

Comment: What does your input df look like?

Comment: "ohlcv" and time is the index(even when it was deleted i was getting errors)but time is not well formatted I suppose it's in unix timestamp formbat.

Comment: Without a sample of either the csv or df.head(), it is hard to comment, or attempt to reproduce.

Comment: It has been added.

Comment: Same problem for me (version 1.0.0). Unfortunately, it seems that bta-lib is not an active library anymore. I recommend you to use ta-lib instead.

Answer (score 1):

Set Open time as index

```
df=pd.read_csv('prices.csv')
df = df.set_index(['Open Time'])
sma=btalib.sma(df,period=9)
rsi=btalib.rsi(df,period=14)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the RSI function by assigning 'close' as float. It was stored in the pandas dataframe as str, and RSI function didn't like it. But SMA somehow worked normally when it was still a str.

```
df['close'] = df['close'].astype(float)
```

However... The bta_lib also uses append function from pandas, which is now deprecated. I went rogue and edited the library a little bit to fix this issue and then the RSI worked just fine. I changed lines.py line 302 to this:

```
trailer = pd.concat([trailprefix, series[p2:]])
```

Don't know if your issue is the same but hope this helps someone.